# XAML Grid ColumnDefinitions seem to change when items added to CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to make a simple .NET Maui project that adds tasks to a list and has a delete button as a swipe item. The Grid's ColumnDefinitions are set to "75*, 25*", but when the C# code adds an object to the list (CollectionView), the definitions seem to be changed to 50%, changing the size of the button and the text entry field, which are both on the same row. The definitions seem go back into place when all items are deleted. I am very new to .NET Maui and any help would be much appreciated!

MauiProgram.cs

```
using MauiApp2.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiApp2;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModel;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject {

    public MainViewModel() {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<string> items;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string text;

    [RelayCommand]
    void Add() {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text)) {
            return;
        }
        Items.Add(text);
        // add our item
        Text= string.Empty; 
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    void Delete(string s) {
        if (Items.Contains(s)) {
            Items.Remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using MauiApp2.ViewModel;

namespace MauiApp2;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="100, Auto, *"
          ColumnDefinitions="75*, 25*"
          Padding="10"
          RowSpacing="10"
          ColumnSpacing="10">

        <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Source="dotnet_bot.jpg"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter task"
           Text="{Binding Text}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>

        <Button Text="Add"
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"/>

        <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <Grid Padding="0,5">
                            <Frame>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                                   FontSize="24"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: So which control is affected by this exactly?

Comment: Does it still happen if you used a fixed height for row 1?  `RowDefinitions="100, 40, *"`. Seems to be a layout bug, so avoiding `Auto` might help it realize that it doesn't need to change layout of those elements.

Comment: I tested the code you provided but there is no such situation as you described. And this the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/WCERWE5). My versions of emulator are Android 13.0 - API 33 and Android 12.1 - API 33